# Bytes Read from PDF are skipped

Tags: java, process, command, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
class BS{

    public void pStr(){
        try{
            String command="cat /usr/share/doc/bash/rbash.pdf";
            Process ps=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            InputStream in  = ps.getInputStream();
            int c;
            while((c=in.read())!=-1){
                System.out.print((char)c);
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new BS().pStr();
    }
}
```

> jabira-whosechild-lm.local 23:54:00 % java BS|wc 
>        384    2003   43885
>
> jabira-whosechild-lm.local 23:54:05 % wc /usr/share/doc/bash/rbash.pdf
>        384    2153   43885 /usr/share/doc/bash/rbash.pdf
>
> Why do i see the difference in the number of characters that are read
>   and printed to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `InputStream.read()` reads only one byte.

Your source code line `System.out.print((char)c);` is wrong.  The method `PrintStream.print(char c)` is called and this method writes two bytes for some non-ASCII character values.

You need to call a method that always writes one byte value.  The correct method is `System.out.write(c);`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it that the number of characters is the same, but the number of words are different?

I'm guessing that somewhere in your `c=in.read()` and `print((char)c)` code there is some encoding issues going on.

Can you save the output to another PDF file and do a binary compare of them? If they are identical then that's really weird! If they're not, then you might find a clue in the differences.